# After RevenueCat Implementation, I can not reach any static variable or classes from my main ViewController

Tags: swift, uikit, swift-package-manager, revenuecat

After I implement RevenueCat with Swift Package Manager, everything works fine till user verification process. I create a checkStatus function:

```
class SettingsController: UIViewController {

static var subscriptionStatus = false

Purchases.shared.getCustomerInfo {(customerInfo, error) in

            if let error = error {
    
                print("Get Customer Status Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    
            } else {
    
                if customerInfo?.entitlements[RevenueCatAPI.entitlementID]?.isActive == true {
    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
                        SettingsController.subscriptionStatus = true
    
                        print(SettingsController.subscriptionStatus)
    
                    }
    
                } else {
    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
                        SettingsController.subscriptionStatus = false
    
                        print(SettingsController.subscriptionStatus)
    
                    }
    
                }
    
            }
    
        }
```

I need to reach that subscriptionStatus result from my mainViewController but it is imposible now. Before the implementation I have already used lots of static variable and they still work and reachable for now but when I delete them I can’t add them again… Please Help Me? What I missed?

I read all Documentation again and again implement all details.
I try to add delegate to change variable in my Main ViewController but even if I declare newly in my Main ViewController I cant reach that too...

Comment: Please do not edit your question with the answer. If you feel it will help future readers, post an actual answer below. It's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question, just don't add the answer to the question. If you don't think it will help others, please delete your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments end edits. I'm totally new in here I'm going to be more careful about post rules.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode didn't work but I closed every ViewController.swift page from Xcode one by one and now everything fixed. If you encounter such a problem, please just close and reopen the pages.